# New to TypeScript, Errors converting JS to TS learning as I go

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

I'm converting an existing Reactjs project to typescript. I'm also learning TS as I go on this project. I am getting a few errors that I am not sure how to navigate and can't seem to find a good answer on Google.

One of my errors, I am pulling a useState boolean from my useContext into my protected route:

> Property 'loggedIn' does not exist on type '{}'.

Protected Route:

```ts
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useAuthContext } from "../context/AuthContext";
import { ReactNode } from "react";

// type ProtectedRouteProps = {
//   children: ReactNode;
// };

export const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }: any) => {
  const { loggedIn } = useAuthContext();
  if (!loggedIn) {
    // user is not authenticated
    return <Navigate to="/" />;
  }
  return children;
};
```

My AuthContext:

```ts
import { useState, createContext, useContext, ReactNode } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const AuthContext = createContext({});

export function useAuthContext() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}
type AuthProviderProps = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

export function AuthProvider({ children }: AuthProviderProps) {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState<boolean>(
    localStorage.getItem("loggedIn") === "true"
  );

  const [selectedDogs, setSelectedDogs] = useState<number[]>([]);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  function setDogMatch(data: number[]) {
    setSelectedDogs(data);
    navigate("/dog-match");
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        loggedIn,
        setLoggedIn,
        selectedDogs,
        setDogMatch,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Not sure what I am missing for that type and where it would need to be set if in my AuthContext or Protected Route.

I also created another error myself my SearchFilter.tsx. Error:

> Parameter 'props' implicitly has an 'any' type.
> Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Here's my SearchFilter.tsx not sure what to do with that map type error. My SearchFilter.tsx takes in data from an API containing strings(dog breeds) and numbers(dog ids):

```ts
import Select from "react-select";


export default function SearchFilters(props) {
  const options =
    props.data &&
    props.data.map((data) => {
      return { value: data, label: data };
    });

  return (
    <div className="dropdown-container">
      <h4>{props.name}</h4>
      <Select options={options} isSearchable={true} {...props} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

To expand further on Part 2: here is what is being passed into props for my SearchFilter.tsx:

```tsx
<SearchFilters
            name="MIN AGE"
            data={Age_Menu}
            value={[minAge]}
            onChange={setMinAge}
          />
          <SearchFilters
            name="MAX AGE"
            data={Age_Menu}
            value={[maxAge]}
            onChange={setMaxAge}
          />
          {ageAlert && (
            <Alert
              variant="danger"
              onClose={() => setAgeAlert(false)}
              dismissible
            >
              <p>Maximum Age Cannot be less than Minimum Age</p>
            </Alert>
          )}
          <SearchFilters
            name="SORT BY"
            options={Sort}
            value={[selectedSort]}
            onChange={setSelectedSort}
          />

          <>
            <SearchFilters
              name="BREEDS"
              data={dogBreeds}
              placeholder="All Breeds"
              value={selectedBreeds}
              onChange={handleSelectedBreeds}
              isMulti
            />
          </>
          <>
            <SearchFilters
              name="STATES"
              data={getStates}
              placeholder="All States"
              value={selectedStates}
              onChange={handleSelectedStates}
              isMulti
            />
          </>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Currently the type of the value the context holds is being inferred from the default value given to `createContext`, which does not have a `loggedIn` field.

You could instead set the type explicitly through the generic parameter to `createContext`, e.g. `createContext<T>(defaultVal)`. Alternatively, pass a default value that contains all the type information.

```
const AuthContext = createContext({
    loggedIn: false,
    setLoggedIn: (val: boolean) => {},
    selectedDogs: [] as number[],
    setDogMatch: (val: number[]) => {}
});
```

2. It seems like `props.data` should be an array, but you have typed it as either a `string` or a `number`.

```
type Props = {
  data: (string | number)[]
  name: string
};
```

```
const options = props.data?.map(data => ({ value: data, label: data }));
```

Comment: So part 1 of your response was able to work with some adjusting on my end. part 2. ended up throwing more errors. I am not sure if I had my types right to begin with when I set it, I wasnt sure if I was doing that one correct. I did edit my question so you could see how it initially was before I put any type.

Comment: @NewBeeee What is the error after applying the second part of the answer?

Comment: Never mind  you were right, I was just trying to put props into my types Props to and that was throwing the error. went from 24 to 30 more errors to fix but only on two big pages to go  lol then im done transitioning

Comment: if i have a passed a component a function and accessing it as a props, how do you set types for functions?

Comment: @NewBeeee You can set the type like `{propName(arg: ArgType): returnType}`.

Comment: Here is a function being passed a prop: 

` const handlePrevPage = () => {
    if (currentPage > 1) {
      if (currentPage === startPageIndex) {
        setStartPageIndex(currentPage - Max_Page);
        setEndPageIndex(currentPage - 1);
      }
      props.prevPage();  ** This is what needs a type set**
      setCurrentPage((curr) => curr - 1);
    }
  };`

the prevPage() is what it says needs a type set.

Comment: @NewBeeee If it takes no arguments and doesn't return anything, then it can be `{prevPage(): void}`

Comment: `Property 'prevPage' does not exist on type 'Props'.` Thats the Error it gives.

so I would do something like this  types Props ={prevPage(): void } ?

Comment: @NewBeeee Yes, that is what I was referring to.

Comment: that ended up throwing `This expression is not callable.
  Type 'void' has no call signatures.`

Comment: @NewBeeee Can't reproduce. Works fine [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAZygXigbzHCA3GAQwHMIAKASgC4o8EBLAEwF8BuAKHoFswE5goAKiiFUAJQiEAxgIBmiLlADkuacCUd2sgK4A7GfQS6oAWRABhBDzI4kyGvDsUs7KG6i2UAOhz4ipSg53KFxgbThjAB5GejwAPgBlK2hgCAAPYC8syIB6GPiOZnZ2SLNLHg9cAhIINExKdDioKSNkBAAbCC92hGIyJV9q0mbCds7GJQpmHLiOIA).

Comment: hmm okay i see what I had different. could you show me this one that you mentioned `{propName(arg: ArgType): returnType}.`

Comment: @NewBeeee That's just specifying the types of the parameters. It works the same way as typing any other value.

Comment: @NewBeeee If you have more issues, it is best to ask a new question instead of using the comments.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Property 'loggedIn' does not exist on type '{}'.**

```js
export function useAuthContext() {
  return <{ loggedIn: any }>useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

**2. Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string | number'. Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'.**

You're calling `.map()` on `props.data`, which is of type `string | number`. `.map()` is only callable on objects which are iterable. Your *SearchFilter.tsx* is unclear about the exact type, so I'm only guessing.

```js
type Props = {
  [_: string | number]: any
}
```

This will make this error go away, but may introduce another error somewhere else.